# Getting items from an api using django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the amount value from the available field when I retrieve a blance from Stripe. I have the following response:

```
{
  "available": [
    {
      "amount": 10302,
      "currency": "cad",
      "source_types": {
        "card": 10302
      }
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "object": "balance",
  "pending": [
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "currency": "cad",
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get the available amount, so I wrote the following:

```
available = balance['available']
```

as a response I am getting the following:

```
[<StripeObject at 0x110d45a98> JSON: {
  "amount": 10302,
  "currency": "cad",
  "source_types": {
    "card": 10302
  }
}]
```

But how can I get access to the 'amount' part?
I tried:

```
amount = available['amount']
```

So I am receiving:

```
TypeError at /en/accounts/profile/
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

as an error.

Comment: I added the error I am receiving, and yes I am using the Stripe library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`balance['available']` contains a dictionary (`{}`) *inside* of a list (`[]`). Therefore, the dictionary is stored as the first element of the list, and has to be accessed using `available[0]`. You can get the value that corresponds to the `'amount'` key by typing `available[0]['amount']`.

Comment: @RiadC Glad I could help!